# JavaScript and XML and HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, xml, replace

Using JavaScript to create an xml file (for later saving in PDF).  When user enters some HTML characters, like < and >, these cause problems because the program thinks they are Beginning and End HTML tags.  We’ve tried the Replace function but have not found the correct Syntax yet.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to to correctly HTML-escape your text before inserting it into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You might try :

```
'<foo><bar></foo></bar>'.replace(/>/g, '&lt;').replace(/</g, '&gt;')
```

The `g`at the end of the regex is really important b/c otherwise it will only replace the first occurence.